# Pasar sintáxis de consulta de sql server a oracle 11g

Tags: sql

tengo un fragmento de sql que ejecuto desde sql server . Como podría ejecutar lo mismo pero desde oracle, en sql developer?

```
DECLARE @PENDIENTES VARCHAR(50)
SET  @PENDIENTES=(select count(AD.ESTADO) as PENDIENTES 
from eidemo04.APROBACION_DETALLE AD
where  AD.ESTADO='Pendiente' AND AD.IDENTIDAD='245a747a-d473-4dc7-82fa-29707b1005b3')
PRINT 'pendientes:'+@PENDIENTES
```

Esto es lo que intenté en oracle y da error de sintáxis:

```
DECLARE PENDIENTES VARCHAR2
BEGIN
select INTO PENDIENTES count("AD".ESTADO) as PENDIENTES 
from APROBACION_DETALLE "AD"
where  "AD".ESTADO='Pendiente' AND "AD".IDENTIDAD='245a747a-d473-4dc7-82fa-29707b1005b3'
PRINT 'pendientes:'+PENDIENTES
END
```

Mensaje de error:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ; not null range default character
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: Hola! ¿Intentaste algo? Si así fue, ¿qué error obtuviste?

Comment: Agrega por favor, el mensaje completo del error.